# How do I pre-fill a form with current user information, if user is logged in?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I already have the data saved in the API when a user signups or logins. I need to get current user information from the API and need to pre-fill a form.

Comment: please, show some code

Answer (score 2):

You can use Auth::user() to get user information in the backend. If you have an API, you should have some kind of authorization implemented. For example with token. You need to fetch the user data from that token (or other authorization method).